# How to reduce spacing between chapters in table of content?

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents

I would like to reduce the spacing between the chapter entries in my table of content. I haven't been able to find a problem similar to what I would like solved.

A minimal work of my report is shown below. This gives a large spacing in the table of content between eg. results and conclusion, between conclusion and Appendix A and so on.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,fleqn]{report}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents 

\chapter{introduction}
\section{first section}
\section{second section}

\chapter{Main matter}
\chapter{Results}
\chapter{Conclusion}
\chapter{Appendix A}
\chapter{Appendix B}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `tocloft` package and its `\cftbeforechapskip` command to achieve your desired spacing:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,fleqn]{report}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{3pt}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents 

\chapter{introduction}
\section{first section}
\section{second section}

\chapter{Main matter}
\chapter{Results}
\chapter{Conclusion}
\chapter{Appendix A}
\chapter{Appendix B}

\end{document}
```

**OUTPUT:**
[image]

Comment: I got this error:

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \cftbeforechapskip

any suggestion to fix?

Answer (score 6):

Or you could use package `tocbasic`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,fleqn]{report}

\usepackage{tocbasic}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  beforeskip=.2em plus 1pt,% default is 1em plus 1pt
  pagenumberformat=\textbf
]{tocline}{chapter}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents 
\chapter{introduction}
\section{first section}
\section{second section}
\chapter{Main matter}
\chapter{Results}
\chapter{Conclusion}
\chapter{Appendix A}
\chapter{Appendix B}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can do that in a simple way with `titletoc`. In the following code, the vertical spacing aboce the entrys is set in the first mandatory  argument of the  `\titlecontents` command. I set it to `\medskip` for chapters, but you change it at will:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,fleqn]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titletoc}

    \titlecontents{chapter}
    [0em] %
    {\medskip\bfseries}
    {\thecontentslabel\quad}%numbered chapters
    {}%numberless chapter
    {\hfill\contentspage}

    \titlecontents{section}[1.72em]{\smallskip}%
    {\thecontentslabel.\enspace}%numbered sections
    {}%numberless section
    {\titlerule*[1.2pc]{.}\contentspage}%

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{introduction}
\section{first section}
\section{second section}

\chapter{Main matter}
\chapter{Results}
\chapter{Conclusion}
\chapter{Appendix A}
\chapter{Appendix B}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With titletoc the following did the trick for me:

```
\usepackage{titletoc}

\titlecontents{chapter}
    [0em] %
    {\bfseries}
    {Chapter \thecontentslabel\quad}%numbered chapters
    {}%numberless chapter
    {\hfill\contentspage}

\titlecontents{section}[1.72em]{\vspace{-10pt}}%
    {\thecontentslabel.\enspace}%numbered sections
    {}%numberless section
    {\titlerule*[0.5pc]{.}\contentspage}%
```

Note the negative vspace.